# Arithmetic operation in C gives weird value

Tags: c

I'm starting with C on my studies and I have a problem with an operation in my program.

Program is counting cm's to cal.

Here's code

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int main(){
> double a;
> double b;
> double c;
> b=2,54;
>     printf("Witaj w programie dla kulturystów. Przeliczy on centymetry na cale.\n\n");
>     getchar();
>     printf("Podaj dlugosc w centymetrach bez jednostki miary\n\n");
>     scanf("%u", &a);
>     c=a*b;
>     printf("Oto Twoj wynik w calach:%.2f\n\n", c);
>     getchar();
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Thank's for help!

Comment: And the problem would be...?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is unfortunately much too broad to get useful answers. Please try to narrow down your problem to the specific bit that you don't understand. Also, translating the strings in your code to english is likely to help since it will help us understand, what your code is supposed to do, and consequently what the solution to your problem could be.

Comment: well, everything is cool with programe, problem was "%lf". Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%u", &a);
```

This is wrong.

`u` conversion specifier requires a pointer to an `unsigned int` but `&a` is a pointer to `double`.

Also:

```
b=2,54;
```

is not equivalent to `b = 2.54;` but to `b = 2;`

Comment: The right one is "%llf".

Comment: `=` is higher precedence than `,`, so `b=2,54` assigns 2 to `b` and evaluates to 54 (immediately discarded).

Comment: @Kevin well spotted, edited my answer.

Comment: @Sorin - are you sure?  Thought it was `"%lf"` for double.

Comment: Well, still the same. Operation x*2,54 gives -25400000000000000 :D

Comment: @ryyker I thought it was. I've always used it. According to http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_670.html they both work. Same reason why long long and int are the same in gcc.

Comment: OK, got it. It's not %llf but %lf as @Sorin said. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Sorin - in this case you are right.  However beware the _subtle_ differences between format specifiers for `scanf()` and `printf()` especially when it comes to dealing with the `l`, `ll`, modifiers applied to data requiring high precision.  `ll` may be appropriate for one, while it is not for the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

```
b=2,54;
```

and

```
scanf("%u", &a);
```

you may try with

```
 scanf("%llf", &a);
```

and

```
 b=2.54;
```

`&a` is a pointer to double and you are looking for `u` as a pointer to an unsigned int

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to *Enter the length in centimeters without units \ n \ n*

The scanf format code you should use to accept a double is "%lf"

Change `scanf("%u", &a);`
To `scanf("%lf", &a);`

Also Because of the assignment:
b=2,54;

b == 2.0;   (i.e. 2, 54 is not == 2.54)

So the statement `c=a*b;` (once you have applied the above correction to scanf) evaluates to `c = a*2.0;`   Correct the `2, 54` to `2.54` and you will have a good conversion!

In general, here are the format strings for `scanf()`, `fscanf()`, `sscanf()`:

`%hi`    to input a **short**
 `%i`     for an **int**
 `%li`    for a **long**
 `%f`     for a **float**
 `%lf`    for a **double**
 `%Lf`    for a **long double**
 `%c`     for a **char** (or `%i` to input it as a number)
 `%s` for a **string** (**char *** or **char []**)